# how can I get the SVN head version number in shell and this shell is running continously using the crontab

Tags: perl, bash, shell, svn

cat sample.pl

```
$svn_rev = `svn info -r HEAD | grep Revision: | cut -c11- `;
$rev = `svn info | grep Revision | cut -d' ' -f2` ;
print "SVN Rev of the HEAD:$svn_rev\n";
print "SVN Rev of the Working:$rev\n";
```

cat sample.sh

```
perl sample.pl
```

now running the script like :

```
./sample

SVN Rev of the HEAD:600
SVN Rev of the Working:590
```

But whenever running continuously using crontab:

```
* * * * *  root  /home/sample.sh > /home/sampleout.txt
```

but here cat sampleout.txt

```
SVN Rev of the HEAD:
SVN Rev of the Working:590
```

HEAD revision number shows northing.
Please tell me whats the wrong in above and any help would be appreciated.

Comment: If the cronjob runs as root, root needs to be logged into SVN I think.

Comment: But I getting the Revision of working copy and why not the HEAD rev?

Comment: This is not related to your question; but why do you use perl script then call it from script, you could just write bash script for that.

Comment: Make sure you dont have a typo in your question. here there are 3 different script `sample`, `sample.sh` and `sample1.sh`

Comment: Actually in perl script contains something else code is there apart from that I just write the simple scenario where I got problem.

Comment: Doesn't help you much now but 1.9 will have `svn youngest` which will work like so `$ svn youngest http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf` which returns just the revision number like so: `1550227`

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in your cut command.
Change the cut -c11- to the cut command you have used in the second line (for $rev)

This should solve your problem!

Comment: Could you share the contents of your sample.sh file

Answer (score 0):

May just be a typo in the post but the script  you show is called sample.sh, but in the cron job its sample1.sh, is there maybe a difference between these?

Is the "root" command necassary?, may be best to get it working as your own user first and source your profile in the command to be sure environment is same as when running from command line:

```
* * * * *  . ~/.profile;/home/sample.sh > /home/sampleout.txt
```

Comment: * * * * *  root  /home/sample1.sh > /home/sampleout.txt (mistake by type)                                                   Still same behavior (even same thing in case of shell without using the perl)

Comment: try logging the output of the "svn info -r HEAD" command to a file as well to see what happens and if its different under cron

Comment: Yeah same behavior and not getting the rev.number

Comment: can you post the output of the "svn info -r HEAD" command when run from cron?

Comment: sample.sh (svn_rev=`svn info -r HEAD | grep Revision: | cut -c11- `   echo "SVN Rev of the HEAD:$svn_rev")                                                                   ./sample (SVN Rev of the HEAD:612) but in case of crontab northing printing.

Comment: Thats not showing the output. Can you add this to the start of the sample.sh script "svn info -r HEAD > /home/svnhead.out 2>&1" and post the svnhead.out file that is produced when running from command line and when running from cron?

Comment: When I running from the command line getting the rev.number but in case of the cron unable to get the rev.number.

Comment: I know that. Please do what i asked in my previous comment, in order to help I need to see the actual output of the svn -info command BEFORE it is piped through grep and cut.